# sum of Time complexities

Tags: proof-verification, asymptotics

Question: Say we have $f(n) = O(n)$ and $g(n) = O(n)$, Show (or not) that $f(n) + c g(k) = O(n+k)$

Solution:

We have : $f(n) = O(n) \Leftrightarrow \exists a \ \textrm{ and } \ n_0 \  \textrm{ s.t. } \ f(n) \leq a \cdot n \ \forall \ n \geq n_0$

and similarly: $g(k) = O(k) \Leftrightarrow \exists b \ \textrm{ and } \ k_0 \  \textrm{ s.t. } \ g(k) \leq b \cdot k \ \forall \ n \geq k_0$

so 
$$
f(n) + cg(k) \leq a\cdot O(n) + c \cdot b \cdot O(k)
$$

But at this point I start thinking maybe the statement does not make sense, how could we have one algorithm running on two different input sizes. 
Any Hints would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For $n+k \ge n_0 + k_0$, you have

$$\vert f(n)+ c g(k) \vert \le \vert f(n) \vert + c \vert g(k) \vert \le an+cbk \le \max(a,cb)(n+k)$$

So indeed saying that $f(n) + c g(k) = O(n+k)$ makes sense using [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).